# imwarp with custom function in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

Is there a way to feed the new *imwarp* function in Matlab a custom transformation?
It looks like it's predecessor *imtransform* could do that, but the functionality seems to have disappeared.
Am I missing something?

Comment: what custom transofrmation? `affine2D` seems to be pretty much customizable

Comment: I'm confused. `imwarp` takes a `tform` object the same way `imtransform` did, and there are a couple of examples on the documentation page. Am *I* missing something?

Comment: It seems from the documentation that iwarp can take a tform object generated from one of three builders only : affine2d, affine3d or projective2d. On the other hand, imtransform accepts an object generated by the general builder maketform, that can by either 'affine', 'projective', 'custom', 'box' or 'composite', in any dimension. I was referring to the 'custom' case where you can provide maketform the handle for an arbitrary, user defined function. I did try to use a 'custom'  maketform with imwarp but no success...

Answer (score 0):

You can still use "imtransform" and its companion function "maketform" for custom/non-linear warping.

```
I = abs(checkerboard(20,10,10));
h = @(x,unused) exp(-0.4*x.^2);
tform2 = maketform('custom', 2, 2, [], h, []);
J = imtransform(I, tform2, 'UData', [-1 1], 'VData', [-1 1], ...
                'XData', [-5 5], 'YData', [-5 5]);
subplot(211),imshow(I)
subplot(212),imshow(J)
```